# Password confirmation(form validation) from server-side to client side

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, validation, express

I have Express.js server. Running in node.js. Using javascript server side language. There I have signup sipmle form, register new user and save users in mongoDb. POST method.

```
<form action="/new" method="POST">Name:
  <input type="text" name="name" class="name"/><br/>Phone number:
  <input type="text" name="phone" class="phone"/><br/>email:
  <input type="email" name="email" class="email"/><br/>Password:
  <input type="password" id="p1" name="pass" class="pass"/><br/>Confirm password:
  <input type="password" id="p2" name="confirm" class="confirm"/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm()"/>
</form>
```

Need to create input validation(actualy it's "Password confirm" and "Email")Also need to use "regex". How I can realize this method?I created input data validation on client-side.It's works.Maybe I just need put this code in the server? Searching in google don't give me expected results... I saw many validation methods validator.js but not finde detailed code...Thank you for helping:)

```
<script>
function validateForm (event) {
var p1 = document.getElementById('p1');
var p2 = document.getElementById('p2');
if (p1.value !== p2.value) {
alert('Password check!');
return false;
}
// check email
var email = document.getElementById('email');
// regex
var email_regexp = /[0-9a-zа-я_A-ZА-Я]+@[0-9a-zа-я_A-ZА-Я^.]+\.[a-zа-яА-ЯA-Z]{2,4}/i;
if (!email_regexp.test(email.value)) {
alert('Check email');
return false;
}
}
</script>
```

also here is my registration server side code:

```
 app.use(bodyParser());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name    : String,
  phone: String,
  email : String,
  pass : String,
  confirm : String
});

var user = mongoose.model('emp', Schema);

app.post('/new', function(req, res){

  new user({
    name : req.body.name,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    email: req.body.email,
    pass: req.body.pass,
    confirm: req.body.confirm   
  }).save(function(err, doc){
    console.log(user); 
    if(err) res.json(err);
    else    res.send('Successfully inserted!');

  });
});
```

Comment: Show your client side validation code.

Comment: You are not clear in your question and even you didn't provided the details like which server side language you're using etc.

Comment: ok. Sorry for not clear question. In the future I will be more informative!

Comment: Do you need to have the server side validation cos your client side validation appears to be working ? If yes, then you didn't specified which server side language you're using.

Comment: I use javascript server side language. Express.js.

Comment: did you tried using req.checkBody('email').isEmail(); ? I think it would automatically implement the email regex.

Comment: Eap you righ't. I'm not using " req.checkBody('email').isEmail(); "  But it's works when I not use javascript code on client side! Now I understood  why :) thanks to you!

Comment: That's wonderful, you understood the issue, should I add it as answer or not?

Comment: oh...it's working. But I have trouble with password confirm...need to understood how can I fix this problem...

Comment: sorry for stupid question. I need use this method inside app.post(function)?

Comment: yes, that's where you'll get the posted form members under 'req' object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For validating email you should use-

```
req.checkBody('email').isEmail();
```

For the validation of Password and Confirm Password you should use-

```
req.assert('confirm', 'Password and Confirm Password should be same.').equals(req.body.pass);
var mappedErrors = req.validationErrors(true);
```